Facing problem in pod setup for GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition
Pod File:
target 'DataProcessing' do
#Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!
#Pods for DataProcessing
pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition', '3.2.0'
end
Error:
Undefined symbol: _GPBClearOneof

Undefined symbol: _GULLogBasic
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GDTCORTransport
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GPBCodedOutputStream
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GPBDescriptor
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GPBEnumArray
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GPBEnumDescriptor
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GPBFileDescriptor
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GPBInt32Array
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GPBMessage
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GPBRootObject
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMLogger
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionCookieStorage
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionFetcher
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionFetcherService
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponent
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponentContainer
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponentType
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULUserDefaults
Undefined symbol: OBJC_METACLASS$_GPBMessage
Undefined symbol: OBJC_METACLASS$_GPBRootObject
Undefined symbol: OBJC_METACLASS$_GTMLogger
Undefined symbol: _kGTMSessionFetcherStatusDomain
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
